# Where is the downvote?

Tags: support, voting

Now and then I get a downvote that shows up in "recent achievements".  I go to the associated question, and there are no downvotes shown at all, on answers or comments.  What am I missing?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Perhaps a downvoter removed the downvote again within 5 minutes before the vote was locked?

Comment: Would the downvote stay on the record?  This is the link: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/407845/.  I've seen this before, and wonder if it's a glitch in the system.

Comment: Does the downvote show up on your profile's Reputation tab?

Comment: I assume the Reputation tab is the cup with the star on it.  What shows is that yesterday I received -15 reputation points for Heterodyne Optical Detection. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/407845/.  When I go there, no downvotes are indicated for the question, for any answers, or for any comments.  Maybe I'm overlooking something--

Comment: A downvote will be -2, not -15. This question makes me think you’ve been fortunate enough to have never received a single downvote!

Comment: @S.McGrew No - I mean in [your actual user profile](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/183212/s-mcgrew?tab=topactivity), then clicking Reputation to get [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/183212/s-mcgrew?tab=reputation). *All* events that impact on your rep are shown there. If a downvote originally showed in the Achievements dropdown (the cup on top right) but it doesn't show in your profile, it was almost certainly retracted within 5 minutes.

Comment: Ah-  What happened was an "unaccept".  I didn't know that could be done.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

As shown on [your reputation tab](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/183212/s-mcgrew?tab=reputation), the user *unaccepted* your answer, causing you to lose 15 rep from the accept bonus.

For the record:

- You posted [the answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/407855/62016) on May 24
- OP accepted your answer on May 30
  [image: accepted]
- OP unaccepted your answer on August 22
  [image: unaccepted]

Comment: Hmmmm. This is the kind of situation where you'd normally turn to the [question timeline](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/407845/timeline) or [the answer's](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/407855/timeline), but unfortunately [the timeline view is limited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272892/new-timeline-view-only-shows-last-accept-vote-no-un-accepts) when it comes to un-accepts and re-accepts.

Comment: OMG it’s elephant  ! Welcome to physics.se have a [tour](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/tour) !

Comment: @Fawad Here's why I hate that new contributor stuff. Andrew T. Has been on physics SE a bit and has posted _several_ comments which I remember, yet he gets that new contributor because he hasn't posted certain _kinds_ of content. Ah well.